# htmlagilitypack question to parse list of links

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I've been trying to parse following page.
'https://marumaru.sale/bbs/cmoic/19997'
And get the list of these...

```
'   <td class="list-subject">
            <a href="/bbs/cmoic/19997/137207">'

//The list should have...
/bbs/cmoic/19997/137207
/bbs/cmoic/19997/137206
/bbs/cmoic/19997/137205
...etc
```

Can someone help me to do it with HtmlAgilityPack, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       private List<string> ExtractAllAHrefTags(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlSnippet)
            {
                List<string> hrefTags = new List<string>();
    
                foreach (HtmlNode link in htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                {
                    HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                    hrefTags.Add(att.Value);
                }
    
                return hrefTags;
            }

foreach (var item in hrefTags)
            {
                if(item.IndexOf(@"/bbs/cmoic/")>-1)
                {
                    if (!epilist1.Contains(item))
                    {
                        epilist1.Add(site1 + item);
                    }
                }
            }
```

It worked.